# Webform twig template causes "the form has become outdated" error

Tags: theming, webforms

We want to customize the theme of our webforms. We will want the ability to add markup around individual webform elements (like my_element_01 and my_element_02 in the example below)

Below is a very basic twig template that seems like the right path (based a little on [How to access webform elements in webform.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232980/how-to-access-webform-elements-in-webform-html-twig/233856) ). However, when I submit this form I get "The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.".

I have read that the form_id and form_build_id has to be rendered in the template but I am doing that. I am not sure what is wrong or if there is a better approach.

```
{{ element.elements.form_description }}

<form{{ attributes }}>

{{ title_prefix }}

  {{ element.elements.my_element_01 }}
  {{ element.elements.my_element_01 }}

  {{ element.form_build_id }}
  {{ element.form_id }}
  {{ element.actions }}

{{ title_suffix }}

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was I was not rendering out the {{ element.form_token }} element. I added that element and it works:

```
{{ element.elements.form_description }}

<form{{ attributes }}>

{{ title_prefix }}

  {{ element.elements.my_element_01 }}
  {{ element.elements.my_element_02 }}

  {{ element.form_build_id }}
  {{ element.form_id }}
  {{ element.form_token }}
  {{ element.actions }}

{{ title_suffix }}

</form>
```

This works which is why I submitted it as an answer. I do think it could be better written. This would require effectively using the twig 'without' filter which I can't get to work. I am creating a separate post about that as I feel they are different topics. The basic idea is I shouldn't have to fish or remember to render all the items that make up a drupal form such as form_build_id, form_id, form_token, or actions. I should render the entire element array and hide the fields I want to wrap in markup. Then I can explicitly render those fields. Something like:

```
{{ element.elements.form_description }}

<form{{ attributes }}>

{{ title_prefix }}

  {{ element|without('elements) }}

  {{ element.elements.my_element_01 }}
  {{ element.elements.my_element_02 }}

{{ title_suffix }}

</form>
```

But that currently renders my_element_01 and my_element_02 twice.